# iTunes Connect: Company Name with Special Characters

Tags: ios, app-store, special-characters, app-store-connect, distribution

When I created my App in iTunes Connect, I've chosen "Bühne GmbH" for the company name.

But now, everywhere it is displayed, it only shows as "B�hne GmbH".
Im a bit afraid now. Is this going to be displayed like this in the AppStore? And what have I done wrong, or is it just Apple not using UTF for the company name?

Besides that, "Bühne GmbH" works just fine as the app's name.

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to contact Apple?

Thanks a lot

### EDIT:

I asked them to change it, but they do NOT allow special characters in the company name, they have to be ASCII, i think.
It will now be displayed as "Buehne GmbH", which is kinda ugly, but yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion contacting Apple will be a good idea, because according to [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf):

> Note: The first time you add an app is your only chance to set
>   a company name distinct from your legal entity name .

So my suggestion is don't take risk, contact Apple.

Comment: Thanks! I will post their answer as it may be helpfull for others.

Comment: @Cornyfisch : Much appreciated, thanks for the comment. Please post that, when you get the answer.